# Finding Unmanaged Memory Leak in .NET Application

Tags: c#, .net

I have created an application which reads a file and fetches meta data of the file. When I launch the application the private working set is around 8MB (as viewed in Task Manager). When I scan the file, the memory shoots up to 150MB and stays there. If I add additional file using the same instance of the application the memory piles on. To understand this behavior, I used a memory profiler (Red gates) which showed me the following statistics :-

Out of the 150MB of private worker set memory

- Unmanaged Memory :94MB
- Others Resources (string,array etc) : 30MB

This puzzles me as I am not using any un-managed code nor any Pinvoke calls. I have also tried GC.Collect() without success.

Can someone please guide me as to how I can reduce the Unmanaged memory usage of my application and what could be the possible causes for the same.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you can use Reg Gates memory profiler, then I recommend you to look at the retention graph to see who holds the memory that is not released.

Comment: A brush or Pen (Winforms) is considered as unmanaged code in RedGate, because they are handles to native brushes or pens.

Comment: Most likely the unmanaged calls are coming when fetching the meta data.<br>
Are you disposing all streams and objects which offer a IDisposable interface correctly?<br>

Comment: You are using lots of unmanaged code and pinvoke.  Inevitable when you run managed code on an unmanaged operating system.  Pinvoke code that was written by Microsoft, not you.  Focus on the managed classes you see in use.

Comment: Venkat Prabhakar - was the answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 3):

A recent update to ANTS shows you which .NET classes your application's unmanaged memory is used by. After enabling unmanaged memory profiling in the setup screen, navigate to the class list and sort by the new 'unmanaged size' column.

Though you may not have knowingly used unmanaged memory, many .NET Framework libraries do use native resources - for example the imaging libraries.

Comment: Thank you for this, I was searching everywhere on this topic. My program is using close to 2 gigs of memory now from the last version which was only using like 350 megs at the most.